# Sparse matrix storage format designed for row/col manipulation?

Tags: c++, matrix

I am working with a program that needs to access and store data in a sparse matrix. About 40-60% of the matrix will be non-zero, dimensions are anywhere from 14K to 22K elements square.

Here's my problem- I'm going to be performing a **lot** of row and column manipulations. Mainly adding, removing, and swapping. I've looked at most of the existing well known sparse matrix formats (CRS, CCS, COO, the block formats, etc), and most of them don't seem very receptive to these kinds of operations. The moment you start adding and removing entire rows or columns, you land up having to update all the elements to either side of the manipulated row/col, and that's something I'd like to try and avoid if possible (it has occurred to me that you could probably manage elements in such a way that their coordinates in the matrix are actually stored as a pair of pointers to a common row or column index, and save yourself from manually updating thousands of elements by simply incrementing or decrementing that value).

Is there anything like that out there?

Comment: since you have that much operations, and you are using a sparse matrix, shouldn't you consider using an Array of linked lists instead ? You would save that wasted space and your operations should be easier, (specially swapping)

Comment: Have you considered `std::unordered_map<std::tuple<int, int>, double, tuplehasher>`?

Comment: How many rows a typical matrix has, and how many columns?  "dimensions are anywhere from 14K to 22K elements square" - does it mean there are totally 14K to 22K elements?  Or a matrix is 14000*14000 to 22000*22000?

Comment: Also, what do you want?  You want to save time?  Or you want to save memory, and ready to sacrifice some time?  Or something else?  Meanwhile, you gave too little information for a meaningful answer.

Comment: If you have infrequent reads and frequent write, you could store a list of changes, and synthesize the modified matrix on demand.

Comment: Only 50% of 0 is not really sparse. I would not even try to save memory here. If you want to optimize row **or** column add, remove or reorder, you could try an array to pointers to rows (resp. columns). But this allows to optimize only one access.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a layer of indirection that serves as an efficient mechanism for swapping, inserting, and deleting rows and columns.

This would be analogous to how virtual memory is managed in modern operating systems. This is just a brief aside: the physical RAM addresses get mapped by the CPU's [memory management unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) into a linear addressing space. The MMU, with the host O/S's help, maps the actual physical RAM addresses into each process's virtual address space. The addresses used by pointers, and other objects, in each process are not real RAM addresses, they are virtual, and are translated by the hardware MMU unit into actual physical RAM addresses. This is why idle processes can be paged out by the host operating system into a swap file or partition, when the system is short on space, and then loaded back in later, into some entirely different area of physical RAM, without the process even being aware of what happened.

Anyway, back on topic, this would be an analogous approach here.

Consider a plain, garden variety two-dimensional `std::map`. Here's your sparse matrix:

```
std::map<size_t, std::map<size_t, value_t>>
```

The first map's dimension, or key, is the row, which gives you a second map, whose dimension/key is the column, and which finally contains your value.

This is pretty straightforward. Nothing earth-shattering here. But as you understand: moving, swapping, and inserting rows and columns becomes quite a bear.

Ok, so let's introducing your own, personalized MMU: your map management unit. It will work, pretty much, like a hardware MMU:

```
std::map<size_t, size_t> rows;
std::map<size_t, size_t> columns;
```

So, in your example, to look up the value for virtual row `R`, columns `C`:

1) `rows[R]` gives you the "physical" row number.

2) `columns[C]` gives you the "physical" column number.

3) Now, you take the "physical" row and column numbers, then go to your two-dimensional `std::map`, and look up your value given the physical row and column.

So, what do we get here? Well, moving an entire row or column now involves a simple update to your map management unit. Remove a value from the `rows` or the `columns` map, and put it back with a different key, the new "logical" row or column. The values in the "physical", two-dimensional map, remain untouched.

That's it. Moving, swapping, or inserting rows becomes a simple operation on your mmu object.

There are two other details that will need to be taken care of:

A) Keep track of which physical rows and columns are not unused, and can be assigned to new logical rows and columns, when they get added.

B) Depending on your use case, it may also be necessary to map physical rows and columns back into the virtual row and column numbers.

Both of these are fairly trivial, straightforward tasks, which can be your homework assignment.